# How can i avoid a function to be overridden in the Child Class in TypeScript ?

Tags: typescript

According to the example given below , i don't want Class B or any other classes which extends `A` be able to override `funcA`.

Can this be done in TypeScript ? If yes then, How ?

```
export class A {
    protected funcA(){

    }
}

export class B extends A {
    //Not able to override funcA()

}
```

Comment: Why have you marked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49002191/3345644) as the correct one? Every inheritor could use `override protected funcA(){` to override the method which you don't want to be overriden.

Comment: @AlexanderAbakumov you are absolutely correct, thanks for pointing it out. The answer to this question is outdated, you can add your version of the answer if needed.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Update for TS 4.3 and above**

Typescript 4.3 adds a new compiler option called `noImplicitOverride` in this [PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/39669). This makes it an error to mistakenly override class methods without the `override` keyword

```
class Base{
    method() {}
    method2 () {}
} 

class Derived extends Base {
    method() {} // err 
    override method2() {} // ok
}
```

(playground does not support the option yet, but works in vs code)

**Original answer pre 4.3**

There is no way to prevent a public/protected member from beeing overriden. The compiler will trigger an error if you to this with private members only. A [feature](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1524) for this has been proposed but not implemented

Comment: It seems it doesn't solve the OP's original intent: being able to disallow a method overriding. If I understand it correctly with the `noImplicitOverride` option, inheritors  are still able to override everything, provided they added that new 'override' keyword.

Answer (score 3):

In Javascript the short answer is, "yes, we can".  I have no experience with Typescript but I understand it is a superset of Javascript so I guess that means if you can do it in Javascript then you can do it in Typescript - please correct me if I am wrong.

Running in `nodejs` in interactive console mode:

```
class A {
    constructor(){
        Reflect.defineProperty(this, 'protectedFn', {
            value: ()=>{ return "hello" },
            configurable: false, 
            writable: false,
            enumerable: true
        })
    }
}
class B extends A {
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.protectedFn=()=>{}
    }
}
class C extends A {
    constructor(){
        super()
        Reflect.defineProperty(this, 'protectedFn', {
            value: (v)=>{ return "goodbye" }
        })
    }
}
class D extends A {
    constructor(){
        super()
        Reflect.deleteProperty(this, 'protectedFn')
    }
}
let a = new A();
let b = new B();
let c = new C();
let d = new D();
a.protectedFn()

c.protectedFn()

d.protectedFn()
```

results in

```
> let a = new A();

> let b = new B();
Thrown:
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'protectedFn' of object '#<B>'
    at new B (repl:4:19)

> let c = new C();

> let d = new D();

> a.protectedFn()
'hello'

> c.protectedFn()
'hello'

> d.protectedFn()
'hello'
```

We see the constructor of `B` invoked a `throw` using the simple assignment form.

The constructor of `C` didn't throw, but it silently failed.  Ouch.  The return result of `Replace.defineProperty` is actually false and should be checked.

Same with `D`.

Interestingly, using ES5 `Object.*` instead ES6 `Replace.*` results in a `throw` upon failure.  Also `Object.deleteProperty` does not exist.