# TypeScript: forbid inheriting class from overriding parent class getters and setters

Tags: typescript

I want to do something like this:

```js
class Animal {
  status: boolean;
  get alive(): boolean { return this.status }
  set alive(status: boolean) { this.status = status }
}
class Dog extends Animal {
  get alive() // type error, alive cannot be overriden, it already exists on parent
}
const otis = new Dog()
otis.alive // boolean, not a type error
```

that is, i want to forbid the subclass from **overriding** the base class getters/setters, but i want to allow the subclass to **access/inherit** them

is this possible in typescript? is there any way to mark a parent's getters and setters as off limits for override in inheriting classes, but still have access to them?

Comment: No there isn't a way to do this in typescript, however you can add some tsconfig settings to make it harder to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49001725/how-can-i-avoid-a-function-to-be-overridden-in-the-child-class-in-typescript There have been may requests for this feature but they don't want to implement it.